# Electron Node and Chrome version outdated?

Tags: node.js, electron

I am trying to develop a webgl desktop app, I am just a bit worried about the versions that electron shows.

I currently get this:

[image]

But chrome is at version 64 I think since jan 2018?
Also my node.js version locally is 9.8.0.

So I was wondering electron comes with it's own nodejs distribution ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Electron comes with its own bundled version of NodeJS. However, note that neither Electron nor NodeJS are required in order to run apps built in Electron.

As for *why* the version of NodeJS bundled with Electron is out of date, you need look no further than **[the official FAQ](https://electronjs.org/docs/faq)**:

> ## When will Electron upgrade to latest Node.js?
>
> When a new version of Node.js gets released, we usually wait for about a month before upgrading the one in Electron. So we can avoid getting affected by bugs introduced in new Node.js versions, which happens very often.
>
> New features of Node.js are usually brought by V8 upgrades, since Electron is using the V8 shipped by Chrome browser, the shiny new JavaScript feature of a new Node.js version is usually already in Electron.

Comment: @Obsidian Age How to upgrade the chromium? Currently it is on 69, how to get it upgraded to 71?