# Electron Chrome version very outdated

Tags: electron

I'm moving from node-webkit to electron and I'm finding some differences in behavior of HTML5 contents. So I've checked chrome version by printing out `process.versions` I get this:

```
{ http_parser: '2.7.0',
  node: '8.9.3',
  v8: '6.1.534.41',
  uv: '1.15.0',
  zlib: '1.2.11',
  ares: '1.10.1-DEV',
  modules: '57',
  nghttp2: '1.25.0',
  openssl: '1.0.2n',
  electron: '2.0.2',
  chrome: '61.0.3163.100' }
```

Comparing to current stable version of Chromium (`67.0.3396.87`) and current version of chromium provided by node-webkit (`67.xxx`), electron's chrome looks very outdated ([one year behind](https://www.chromium.org/developers/calendar)) especially if I look to electron 2.0.2 npm package release date that is only 22 days ago. 
Why? I'm I supposed to update electron's chrome manually somehow?
Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49395723/2550156 for the Why (also possibly duplicate)

Comment: Thanks, but that only answer to the nodejs version update question. In the same FAQ page I've found this about chrome "The Chrome version of Electron is usually bumped within one or two weeks after a new stable Chrome version gets released.". But we're currently one year behind

Comment: well, all I know about it is that it's not equally easy to update to chromium versions. sometimes important parts of code changes entirely. In those cases it's very complicated to merge/refactor. Currently they seem to work on update to [`66`](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/12477)

Comment: And yes, the answer I linked is about node version I missed the difference, sry.

Comment: Thanks pergy for your answer. So the FAQ saying "The Chrome version of Electron is usually bumped within one or two weeks after a new stable Chrome version gets released." it a bit too optimistic in this case ;)

Comment: or they just don't feel the versions on last year "stable" :)